# Как достать мандатную метку из HTTP-запроса?

Tags: веб-программирование, apache, firefox, astra-linux

Не могу найти в доках астры, как Mozilla зашивает мандатную метку в запросы. Нужно ее достать на сервере (который получает запросы) для работы веб приложения, но не очень понятно как. Нашла, что ее Apache может достать, но каким образом и как затем ее передать дальше для работы приложения?

Вот есть такая инфа:

> Браузер зашивает метку в запрос.
> «Запрос обрабатывает веб-сервер с поддержкой мандатных меток, в нашем
> примере — Apache Http Server. Веб-сервер (процесс которого работает в
> режиме минимальной мандатной метки) считывает мандатную метку запроса,
> находит приложение-обработчик запускает его процесс с переданной
> мандатной меткой. Приложение взаимодействует с БД на PostgreSQL,
> ретранслируя в запросах мандатную метку.»

Предложение

> «находит приложение-обработчик запускает его процесс с переданной
> мандатной меткой»

где почитать как это реализовывается? И тоесть получается, что на каждый запрос юзера будет порождаться новый процесс?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RequestHeader unset X-USERMAC
RequestHeader set X-USERMAC %m
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Уже неоднократно просил вас, пожалуйста, воздержитесь от постоянных напоминаний о ваших надуманных домыслах. Очень надеюсь на ваше понимание. Спасибо!